# How to detect which imageView is?

Tags: swift, imageview, extension-methods

As title, now I make an extension of UIImageView.

And also, I make a function do something I want, but I need to detect which imageView is right now.

What should I do?

Using "tag" or "accessibilityIdentifier" ?

If doing this with "tag", how can I get its memory location because I want to convert it as its tag.

If there has better, please share your opinions !!

Thanks so much!!

> Example code below :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    im1.doSomething()
    im2.doSomething()
    im3.doSomething()
    im4.doSomething()
    im5.doSomething()
}

extension UIImageView {

    func doSomething() {
        // do Something but need to know which imageView is right now
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like an incorrect usage for extensions (maybe a fileprivate extension, but still). Why not just create a function inside your VC `func doSomething(to: UIImageView)` ?  You could also subclass if needed.

Comment: You're right, but reason why I usage extension because I hope that every imageView can use this function. Sorry, could you share your opinion when to usage extension. I feel like I misunderstand about extension , thank you so much

Comment: But if you want every UIImageView to do something (e.g: apply effect? or w/e) why would you want to "detect it's instance". Extensions aren't the way to go in this case in my opinion. An internal function in the vc is enough (you need to explain what will doSomething be)

Comment: OMG, you're right.. If I need every imageView can do this then I don't need to know what imageView is right now, right? If I need to detect the specific imageView then I shouldn't do that in extension, just create function in specific VC and subclass. Sorry, now I know your mean!

Comment: And I figure out that my "doSomething" func is only be used in specific  VC, then the better is just create a func in that VC and imageView just subclass it, am I right?